# Dataset for user stories and corresponding test cases?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

Is there any opensource large dataset of user story mapped to test cases of e-commerce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, I've never seen any dataset that maps to a user story. That's part of the job of a QA Engineer/Analyst: to be able to look at the requirements for a user story and understand, even generate, the necessary test data that is needed! Is it time-consuming to do? Yes, but certainly one that is necessary!

While there are a lot of commonalities in types of software, especially in a black-box perspective, the implementation of software (white-box perspective) will be different.

The one thing we don't know from the OP is how they want to use any data.

- As part of a test automation solution? If so, what is the tech stack in use?
- To setup user accounts in their test environment?
- To use in an exploratory/experiential way? (aka "manual testing")

For a test automation solution, especially one that uses JavaScript, I recommend using [Faker](https://github.com/faker-js/faker). Faker has a bunch of test data available, including:

- Locations - Generate valid looking Addresses, Zip Codes, Street Names, States, and Countries!
- Time-based Data - Past, present, future, recent, soon... whenever!
- Localization - Pick a locale to generate realistic looking Names, Addresses, and Phone Numbers.
- Finance - Create stubbed out Account Details, Transactions, and Crypto Addresses.
- Products - Generate Prices, Product Names, Adjectives, and Descriptions.
- Hacker Jargon - “Try to reboot the SQL bus, maybe it will bypass the virtual application!”
- Names - Generate virtual humans with a complete online and offline identity.
- Numbers - Of course, we can also generate random numbers and strings.